# Sharing a Show Route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a Rails 4 app and I have a `BookingsController`. There are two types of user for my app - `admins` and `guests` and both need to be able to view a `booking` - however, the view is very different depending on the type of user that is viewing the booking.

At the moment I am using a standard RESTful approach for the `admins` and my own actions in my `GuestController` for when the `guests` view bookings.

Is there a better approach to this problem? - and by better I mean is there a way to make the `guests` RESTful too?

Comment: What about namespaced routes ?
`admin/bookings`
`guest/bookings`

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about Namespaces - recently read the docs - would I end up with two controllers for bookings?

Comment: Yes, that's the RESTful approach. Many gems do it in the same way.

Comment: You don't need to share your controller. Share your business logic only. You write that actions are quiet different so what's the purpose putting it in one action ? Moreover including something like `render ('...') if current_user.guest?` it's very straight way to the hell.

Comment: Is it possible to introduce Namespacing now I'm well into my app?

Comment: I certainly don't want to use conditionals!

Comment: better late than never

Comment: so is it a case of copying a pasting controllers into folders and setting up the routes or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Basically as Leszek already suggested go with namespaces. If the logic for both cases in controller is the same you can extract it in two ways:

Leave `BookingsController` as you have now and use inheritance - let your scoped controllers inherit from this non-namespaced controller like this:

```
   # controllers/admin/bookings_controller.rb 
   class Admin::BookingsController < BookingsController
   end

   # controllers/guest/bookings_controller.rb        
   class Guest::BookingsController < BookingsController
   end
```

Second option would me extract all methods to a module (concern)

```
   # concerns/controllers/bookings.rb
   module Controllers::Bookings
     def show
       ...
     end
   end

   # controllers/admin/bookings_controller.rb 
   class Admin::BookingsController < ApplicationController
     include Controllers::Bookings
   end

   # controllers/guest/bookings_controller.rb        
   class Guest::BookingsController < ApplicationController
     include Controllers::Bookings
   end
```

Both ways allow You to override methods that will have different logic. Some people like the first approach, others prefer second. One thing to consider though - Ruby is a single inheritance language, so if You are already subclassing these controllers from some common parent controller then probably going with modules approach will be more flexible.